# Should I add binding.lifecycleOwner=this when I use viewModel?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

In my mind, I should add `binding.lifecycleOwner=this` when I use `viewModel`.

I find many projects such as Code A doesn't add `binding.lifecycleOwner=this`, why?

The Code A is from the project https://github.com/enpassio/Databinding

**Code A**

```
class AddToyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: AddToyBinding
    ...

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_add_toy, container, false
        )

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        //If there is no id specified in the arguments, then it should be a new toy
        val chosenToy : ToyEntry? = arguments?.getParcelable(CHOSEN_TOY)

        //Get the view model instance and pass it to the binding implementation
        val factory = AddToyViewModelFactory(provideRepository(requireContext()), chosenToy)
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(AddToyViewModel::class.java)

        binding.viewModel = mViewModel

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            saveToy()
        }

        binding.lifecycleOwner=this //I think it should add 
    }
```

Comment: Please note! You should use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead `this`. `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` Because view of fragment have smaller lifecycle than fragment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`binding.lifecycleOwner` used for observing `LiveData` with data binding.
Kind of `android:text=@{viewModel.text}` where `val text:LiveData<String>`. View will observe text changes at runtime.

Comment: Is it necessary if we use Flow instead of LIveData?

Comment: @tsil There is no difference what to use. If `ViewDataBinding` has no `LifecycleOwner` all view updates will be accepted only after `invalidate()`.

Answer (score 4):

as far as I understand it,

> binding.lifecycleOwner= this

used in one side to make a subscription to receive messages when liveData is changed (so information in view to be consistent), and in another side to delete observer from list when view and fragment is destroyed (to prevent memory leaks). Fragment's viewLifecycleOwner is more suitable to use as  lifecycleOwner for binding in this way, isn't it?